# Ajax requests not working the same on different browsers

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I have coded my simple web app game using Codeigniter.

[Ninja Gold](http://www.travterrell.com/ninjagold)

Here is where I am confused.  I am using Ajax requests to be able to go to my different routes to return the different amounts of gold from the location buttons.  I wanted to be able to have continuous music in the background...hence this method.

The problem is I am getting this error on Chrome.

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://www.travterrell.com/ninjagold/Ninjas/cave. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://travterrell.com' is therefore not allowed access.
```

When I originally found this error, I had looked up this problem and found that I needed to insert this code into the index file of travterrell.com since the Ninja Gold game is a subindex on my personal website

```
<?php header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *'); ?>
```

I was also instructed to modify my .htaccess file to this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /ninjagold

    #Removes access to the system folder by users.
    #Additionally this will allow you to create a System.php controller,
    #previously this would not have been possible.
    #'system' can be replaced if you have renamed your system folder.
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

    #When your application folder isn't in the system folder
    #This snippet prevents user access to the application folder
    #Submitted by: Fabdrol
    #Rename 'application' to your applications folder name.
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^application.*
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

    #Checks to see if the user is attempting to access a valid file,
    #such as an image or css document, if this isn't true it sends the
    #request to index.php
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
    # If we don't have mod_rewrite installed, all 404's
    # can be sent to index.php, and everything works as normal.
    # Submitted by: ElliotHaughin

    ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
</IfModule>
```

Specifically line 3 where I re-wrote the base.  At first this fixed the problem but now I notice the game doesn't work on Chrome and sometimes works on Safari on the desktop.  It works on Safari mobile but the sound effects when you click the buttons to receive or lose gold doesn't work. Chrome doesn't work on mobile.  Any ideas what the problem is?

Comment: Given link ajax already working in chrome..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not quite sure why you'd put the [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS) in the PHP to be honost. Put it in the `.htaccess` file, like [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13871027/1155833). Also check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20453033/1155833) (same question as previous, for helpful insights).

Quote from answer:

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
</IfModule>
```

Below the 2 `.htaccess` files I use in my own Zend Framework 2 projects. The first one, in the application root, is pretty much for if/when I forget to setup the Apache vhost properly. It redirects everything to the public folders' index.php file.

The second file is the ZF2 default .htaccess. Works like a charm. From when I tried out CodeIgniter 2 (few years ago), I used the same files.

Obviously you should rewrite the base in the first file to your /ninjagold location. However, if your application has a `/public` folder as the point of entry, rewrite it to `/ninjagold/public`.

**root (/) `.htaccess`**

```
RewriteEngine On

# If URL to the application is http://foo.com/path/to/ZendSkeletonApplication/
# the set the base to /path/to/ZendSkeletonApplication/
RewriteBase /

# Remove trailing slash
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

# Below is ZF2 default
RewriteRule ^\.htaccess$ - [F]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} =""
RewriteRule ^.*$ public/index.php [NC,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/public/.*$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]

RewriteRule ^public/.*$ public/index.php [NC,L]
```

**`/public/.htaccess`**

```
RewriteEngine On

# Remove trailing slash
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

# The following rule tells Apache that if the requested filename
# exists, simply serve it.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
# The following rewrites all other queries to index.php. The 
# condition ensures that if you are using Apache aliases to do
# mass virtual hosting, the base path will be prepended to 
# allow proper resolution of the index.php file; it will work
# in non-aliased environments as well, providing a safe, one-size 
# fits all solution.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}::$1 ^(/.+)(.+)::\2$
RewriteRule ^(.*) - [E=BASE:%1]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ %{ENV:BASE}index.php [NC,L]
```

Comment: So the first .htaccess file should work fine correct?  I'm new to CodeIgniter and I'm trying to find more info on .htaccess files.

Comment: It depends on what you're trying to do, which is a bit unclear. You say you're AJAX functions aren't working but then proceed to only talk about your `.htaccess` files. Which leads (me) to believe you're receiving `500 internal server error` responses, or maybe `404 not found`. Most likely the latter. However, if you're linking to something like "website.com/ninjagold/get_me_data", you would need the the first .htaccess in my answer in the root of your project, as it's not your website root, to redirect you from /ninjagold/ to /ninjagold/public...

Comment: Had a quick look around for you, apart from my own knowledge, which is primarily ZF2 based, and found you [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40003236/codeigniter-web-config-or-htaccess-index-php-rewrite-inside-a-subdirectory), seems to be your exact problem; it's about a codeigniter app within a codeigniter app (so in essence, an app in a subdirectory). Not sure about the next one, but [it may be helpful](https://serverfault.com/questions/820040/codeigniter-is-not-working-after-primary-domain-to-subfolder).

Comment: I'm off, back in about 12 hours. If you haven't figured it out by then, leave a comment and/or update your question and I might have another look for you.

Comment: You're welcome ;) If I managed to solve your issue, feel free to mark the answer as solved. If not, you should provide an answer of your own that answers the question. Maybe the question needs an update to be clearer, in case anyone else comes along in the future with a similar/same issue :)

Comment: I actually figured out the problem.  I had <?php header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *'); ?> in my CodeIgniter index file as well as my domain's index file.  When I took that out it of my CodeIgniter index file it stopped the problem.  That conflicted with the root .htaccess file for some reason.